# How to hide second option in condition of first selection with JS / JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got following problem and dont know how to solve it. :(

I want to disable / gray out options in relation to a color-selection.
Every option has a unique value.

For example:

- shirt (green) is only available in XS.
- shirt (blue) is available in S and M.
- shirt (yellow) is not available in L and XL.

Is it possible with something like "if" or an array function?!?!
Is there a code snipped on fiddle?

Thanks for any help and sorry for my non-existing JS knowledge!

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="">
        <label for="test"></label>
        <select name="color" id="color">
          <option value="1">---Select color---</option>
          <option value="2">T-Shirt - green</option>
          <option value="3">T-Shirt - blue</option>
          <option value="4">T-Shirt - yellow</option>
        </select>
    <br />
        <select name="size" id="size">
          <option value="5">---Select size---</option>
          <option value="6">XS</option>
          <option value="7">S</option>
          <option value="8">M</option>
          <option value="9">L</option>
          <option value="10">XL</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sizes_avail = {
    '2': ['6'],
    '3': ['7', '8'],
    '4': ['9', '10']
};
$("#color").change(function() {
    var color = $(this).val();
    if (sizes_avail.hasOwnKey(color)) {
        $("#size option").attr("disabled", true);
        $.each(sizes_avail[color], function(i, size) {
            $("#size option["+size+"]").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    } else {
        $("#size option").attr("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to do with the `.onChange` function in jQuery along with a switch.

[Here is a fiddle with the solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/KYvwP/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can set up an object which captures the valid colours and sizes then you can iterate all the `<option>` elements setting the disabled property based on whether the option's value is in the set of allowed sizes.

```
var availableSizesForColors = {
    '2': ['6'],
    '3': ['7', '8'],
    '4': ['9', '10']
};

// bind the function to the JavaScript 'change' event
$('#color').change(function() { 
    // look up the available colours in the object above for the given value of the shirt colour drop down
    var availableSizes = availableSizesForColors[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];

    // set disabled = true or false if the size option is or is not in the availableSizes array
    $('#size option').prop('disabled', function () { return $.inArray(this.value, availableSizes) == -1 });
});
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu44s/)

Note: You might wann to use a different "array contains" method if you care about the performance of the jQuert `$.inArray` function - see [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)